# OAuth Error: This IP can't make requests for that application

Tags: facebook-graph-api, oauth, facebook-opengraph, facebook-oauth

I just started to get random `This IP can't make requests for that application.` errors with my app. My server's IP address is on my whitelist from my app's settings, and it was working perfectly, but I randomly started to get this error. I've checked my server's IP (even though I already know it's static), I've removed all the entries in the whitelist, but none seem to work. Weird enough, I can test the exact same code from my home and it works! What could be the cause of the problem? This wasn't happening even a few minutes ago, but now I'm getting an error at my server.

Thanks,
Can.

**UPDATE**: I can't seem to remove the whitelist, too. I went to app advanced settings, and the IP's were there again. I deleted them and saved, it says that it's saved but when I scroll down, the IP's are still there. I think it's a serious bug with Facebook. But that [currently un-editable] list DOES contain my server's IP anyway.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Despite the bugs occuring at Facebook (which led me incorrectly to investigate deeper at the Facebook-side), I realized that my web hosting's outgoing connection changes randomly in few hours. The incoming dedicated IP stays as is, but when I try to initiate a connection server-side, I've realized that my server wasn't using the dedicated IP assigned to it. I've contacted GoDaddy, my hosting provider, and they've informed me that the situation is normal and there's no way to fix it even though I have a dedicated IP. I've cleared the whitelist (allowing ALL IP addresses-the default) and the problem is solved. (Facebook, in the meantime, has analyzed and fixed my whitelist issue too, so I could clear the list)

Comment: Good contribution to help understand why it isn't working, while you'd expect it should.

Answer (score 40):

As Victor Hugo Arango A. said, remove all the IPs in the server whitelist and you're good to go. To do this:

1. Go to App Settings
2. Advanced (tab)
3. Security (section)
   remove IP if you see any.

Answer (score 16):

I had the same problem... I just removed all the ip listed in the server whitelist.

I recently bought an ssl certificate with comodo, in hostgator.... they change my IP and everything stop working.... I get this error: "This IP can't make requests for that application."  I think that Facebook servers haven't update the DNS yet, and thats why the error is happening.

So, you can solve the problem removing all the server whitelist ip, in your Facebook app advance configuration....

Answer (score 0):

I had to remove cloudFlare service on my domain