# Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException - Unauthorized source IP address

Tags: php, facebook

im using Go Daddy hosting...

> IP Address 118.139.174.1 Dedicated IP Address 118.139.174.142

from last one month im getting this error from Facebook, i try to fill IP Address in App Setting, but still does not work...

> Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: (#5) Unauthorized source IP
>   address thrown in
>   /home/content/88/9201788/html/stone-game/classes/facebook/base_facebook.php
>   on line 1106

Comment: Can you add the code which you are using, you have an OAuthException - did you search for that yet?

Comment: im using this code.

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '',
 'secret' => '',
));

$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
  try {
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}

with facebook php sdk 3.1

Answer (score 1):

Your outgoing IP address is different from your hosting address. I've ran into the exact same situation about a month ago. I've contacted GoDaddy and I was told that there's nothing to do for fixing the outgoing IP address unless I start using a [virtual] dedicated server. Just delete the whitelisted IP from the list and you'll be fine.

Here, have a look at this: [OAuth Error: This IP can't make requests for that application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12072720/oauth-error-this-ip-cant-make-requests-for-that-application)

Comment: there is no available list, and the IP's may change

Answer (score 0):

I guess Facebook blacklisted your host. Seems that this happens quite often with Go Daddy.

Here is more:

[Login with Facebook : Uncaught OAuthException: (#5) Unauthorized source IP address thrown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12507718/login-with-facebook-uncaught-oauthexception-5-unauthorized-source-ip-addre)

http://support.godaddy.com/groups/web-hosting/forum/topic/fatal-error-uncaught-oauthexception/

Comment: the best you can do is leave go daddy, i guess ;)

Answer (score -1):

You might also be running the API from your Localhost. Try running your application live.