# Devise + Omniauth Facebook invalid credentials

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook-graph-api, omniauth, omniauth-facebook

When I try to log in with omniauth(facebook) I get ***Invalid credentials*** error in production but it works fine in local.

I already added the urls in **Valid OAuth redirect URIs**

The callbacks I get are

**/auth/facebook/callback?code=....**

**CallbacksController#failure**

The gems I have.

- oauth2 (1.2.0)
- omniauth (1.3.1)
- omniauth-facebook (4.0.0)
- omniauth-oauth2 (1.4.0)

Answer (score 0):

The solution was removing my **IP** from **Server IP Whitelist**

[OAuth Error: This IP can't make requests for that application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12072720/oauth-error-this-ip-cant-make-requests-for-that-application/15415614#15415614)