# Unable to sign up in app via facebook

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, facebook-login

Whenever I try to sign up via facebook in my application. I am faced with this issue:

> com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has
>   occurred.[ Unsuccessful debug_token response from
>   Facebook:{"error":{"message":"This IP can't make requests for that
>   application.","type":"OAuthException","code":190,"fbtrace_id":"AiwCzClvFwf"}}
>   ]

Please note that this was working fine a few days ago. I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12072720/oauth-error-this-ip-cant-make-requests-for-that-application) solution but it doesn't work. What am i missing?

Comment: have you added your firebase app url in Facebook developer page settings ?